# Typedef struct pointer to another typedef struct

Tags: c, struct

I have some problems with this code:

```
typedef struct Product {

    char product_code[5];
    int sells;
    int sells_quantity;
}p[3];

typedef struct Seller {
    char seller_code[5];
    Product *ptr;
}seller[5];
```

Why does it give me an error for `Product *ptr`?

Comment: Why have you tagged this C++? A C++ compiler should compile that code just fine. In C, you need `struct Product *ptr;`

Comment: Note that your first `typedef` defines a type `struct Product` (more or less incidentally), and a type `p` that is an array of 3 elements of type `struct Product`.  Similarly, your second `typedef` attempts to define a type `seller` which is an array of 5 elements of type `struct Seller`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try replace your code

```
typedef struct Product {

    char product_code[5];
    int sells;
    int sells_quantity;
}p[3];
```

With

```
typedef struct Product {

    char product_code[5];
    int sells;
    int sells_quantity;
} Product;               // from here the structure type Product is recognized by the compiler.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
typedef struct Product {

char product_code[5];
int sells;
int sells_quantity;
}p[3],Product;

typedef struct Seller {
  char seller_code[5];
  Product *ptr;
}seller[5];
```